# How to enable swagger in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger

I found mention of swagger in the Introductory Slides. But nowhere else. Is is something not finished yet?

Edit: Apparently it's on To Do List.

Is there any good way to document the RestAPI automatically?

Comment: FYI it's recommended to use the newer [Open API](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) feature which also embeds the /swagger-ui/ and implements the newer Swagger v2.0 / Open API spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Trello](http://bit.ly/WYT1bv) it was a "Doing" but has then been moved back to "To Do"; and there's a Swagger.Api module in the github repo, so assuming it's only partially finished.

**Edit**

As pointed out already (but for the sake of completeness, as this was the accepted answer), SwaggerUI is ready for service stack (and holy moly is it awesome). The [Github wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) has been filled out in the last few days, and it's super easy to get it up & running.

Comment: I see, didn't know about the Trello board.

Comment: I remember reading about this in the http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/servicestack chat room that this was still in development.

Answer (score 9):

To enable Swagger for your Service Stack, follow the [Swagger API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) page on Service Stack wiki.

#### Detailed Steps:

1. Run `Install-Package ServiceStack.Api.Swagger` in your package manager console.
2. Enable Swagger plugin in your AppHost.cs with:

   ```
   using ServiceStack.Api.Swagger;

   public override void Configure(Container container)
   {
     ...
     Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Access Swagger UI with `http://localhost:port/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: where to get the source code for `index.html` et al?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's complete and ready now, check out the release notes for v3.9.35 @ https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...sorry if I misunderstood this:

> Is there any good way to document the RestAPI automatically?

...but when I decorate my DTO or service with attributes this:

```
[Route("/hello","GET")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}","POST,GET")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The default metadata page generated by servicestack documents the usage:

[image]

Is this not what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core ServiceStack, So I was installed ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core nuget for Swagger UI.

But that was giving me '500: Undefined Error'.

Then i have removed ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.Core & installed ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.

That's works perfectly.

Comment: The `*.Core` NuGet packages are only for running [ASP.NET Core on the .NET Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx), FYI ServiceStack.Api.Swagger only implements the older Swagger v1.2 API, it's recommended to use the new [Open API](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) feature which implements the newer Open API/Swagger v2.0.